# git emacsclient issues

Tags: emacs, git, emacsclient

I set my editor variable like so:

```
git config --global core.editor "`which emacsclient` -t -s"
```

and get this output whenever I want to edit the message during a commit

```
emacsclient: aliased to /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient -t -s :      
emacsclient:: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'emacsclient: aliased to
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient -t -s '.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you checked the output of`which emacsclient` command? I bet it is

```
emacsclient: aliased to /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient
```

Anyway, your global git config is located `~/.gitconfig` file, so you can check and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the full path "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient -t -s" and not the alias to be the editor worked for me.